# Incorrect Header Check at Zlib when install package geolite2-redist

Tags: node.js, zlib, geolite2

I just got this weird error and did not find a result.
Everything was still fine yesterday. But when I start reinstall my packages ( geolite2-redist) , it gives me this error:

`error /home/ubuntu/node_modules/geolite2-redist: Command failed.                                                                                                                                                                Exit code: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 Command: node scripts/postinstall.js                                                                                                                                                                                                         Arguments:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   Directory: /home/ubuntu/node_modules/geolite2-redist                                                                                                                                                                            Output:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      Downloading MaxMind databases from mirror...                                                                                                                                                                                                 node:events:368                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event                                                                                                                                                                                                         ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   Error: incorrect header check                                                                                                                                                                                                                    at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (node:zlib:190:17)                                                                                                                                                                                      Emitted 'error' event on Gunzip instance at:                                                                                                                                                                                                     at Gunzip.onerror (node:internal/streams/readable:773:14)                                                                                                                                                                                    at Gunzip.emit (node:events:390:28)                                                                                                                                                                                                          at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)                                                                                                                                                                                         at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)                                                                                                                                                                                    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {`

Have anyone got this error like me before ?